# How to add delay in php

Tags: javascript, php

for account verification process when  user click on verfication link . He /She instantly redirects to dashboard . But  I want to give a confirmation message that his/her account has been verified for some seconds.
here is my code

```
                    <?PHP
require_once 'include/Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();




if(isset($_GET['username'])&&isset($_GET['q']))
{  
 $username= $_GET['username'];  

$hash= $_GET['q'];  




 $salt = "498#2D83B631%3800EBD!801600D*7E3CC13";

         $resetkey = hash('sha512', $salt.$username);


        if($hash==$resetkey){

            $user = $db->activateAccount($username);

             if ($user != false) {
        // user is found
        echo '<script>';
    echo 'document.getElementById("result_status").innerHTML = "<strong>Congratulations!  Your Account has been verified .</strong>"';

    echo '</script>';


       $passwords=$db->getPasswordFromUsername($username);

    $users = $db->loginUserWithMdfPassword($username, $passwords);
     if ($users != false) {
        // password is found

       $properlyLogged=true;


if($properlyLogged) {
    // season for storing data start here

session_start();

$_SESSION['username']=$username;


header('Location: http://localhost/mywebsite/dashboard.php');

exit();
 // season for storing data end  here

    }}


}

        }else {
            echo '<script>';
      echo 'document.getElementById("result_status").innerHTML = "<strong>Session has been expired.</strong>"';

    echo '</script>';




}}



?>
```

Comment: Use the Sleep function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Comment: how can i use it in my code ? can you tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would probably be easier with a JavaScript approach.

instead of `header('Location: http://localhost/mywebsite/dashboard.php');`

put

`echo '<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = "http://localhost/mywebsite/dashboard.php"}, 5 * 1000);</script>'`

This will wait for X * 1000 milliseconds (in my example, 5 seconds) and then redirect to the destination.

Answer (score 1):

`sleep` wont work for what you want.
you're redirecting your user using `header('location:...');` and you cannot modify header information after you've outputted data (ie - showed message to user).
you'll have to preform the redirect using javascript with a `setTimeout`

```
<?PHP
 require_once 'include/Functions.php';
 $db = new DB_Functions();
 if(isset($_GET['username'])&&isset($_GET['q']))
 {  
   $username= $_GET['username'];  
   $hash= $_GET['q'];  
   $salt = "498#2D83B631%3800EBD!801600D*7E3CC13";
   $resetkey = hash('sha512', $salt.$username);
   if($hash==$resetkey){
        $user = $db->activateAccount($username);
         if ($user != false) {
    // user is found
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'document.getElementById("result_status").innerHTML = "<strong>Congratulations!  Your Account has been verified .</strong>";';
// set timeout for 3 seconds - then redirect
    echo "setTimout(function(){window.location.href = 'http://localhost/mywebsite/dashboard.php';},3000)"
echo '</script>';

   $passwords=$db->getPasswordFromUsername($username);

$users = $db->loginUserWithMdfPassword($username, $passwords);
 if ($users != false) {
    // password is found

   $properlyLogged=true;


   if($properlyLogged) {
       // season for storing data start here
       session_start();
       $_SESSION['username']=$username;
       //comment out header redirect
       //header('Location: http://localhost/mywebsite/dashboard.php');
       exit();
      // season for storing data end  here
}}
```